# Searching a stable js-Tree PlugIn, jsTree or Ext-Js Tree?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, extjs

Im evaluating a tree PlugIn for a Admin Interface in Intranets (**Speed and Size do not matter**). The Internet and a expensive search turned jsTree and the ExtJs' Libraries Tree up as the most complete ones. The differences seem rather minimal, so my questions are:

Which is more **stable**?  As jsTree is a jQuery Plugin, does ExtJs **play with jQuery**, too?  Can jsTree look as **polished** as ExtJs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone is interested, we will end up using jsTree as there is no explicit garantee, whether ExtJs is OSS in the foreseeable future.

Comment: And now we begin transitioning to jqGrid's Tree component in many cases.

Comment: And now we write it in our own with recursive templates in agular